# Sequence classification with LSTM, Error when checking input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am building my first neural network with LSTM and I have an error in the input size.

I guess the error is in the input parameters, in the size, the dimension but I can not understand the error.

```
print df.shape

data_dim = 13
timesteps = 13
num_classes = 1
batch_size = 32

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences = True, stateful = True,
               batch_input_shape = (batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)))

model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences = True, stateful = True))

model.add(LSTM(32, stateful = True))

model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'relu'))

#Compile.
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.summary()

#Fit.
history = model.fit(data[train], label[train], epochs = iteraciones, verbose = 0)

#Eval.
scores = model.evaluate(data[test], label[test], verbose = 0)

#Save.
cvshistory.append(history)
cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
```

shape:

```
(303, 14)

summary:
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_19 (LSTM)               (32, 13, 32)              5888      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_20 (LSTM)               (32, 13, 32)              8320      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_21 (LSTM)               (32, 32)                  8320      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_171 (Dense)            (32, 1)                   33        
=================================================================
Total params: 22,561
Trainable params: 22,561
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The error output tells me the following:

```
---> 45   history = model.fit(data[train], label[train], epochs = iteraciones, verbose = 0)

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_19_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (226, 13)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LSTM requires input of shape `(batch_size, timestep, feature_size)`. You are passing only two dimension features. Since `timesteps=13` you need to add one more dimension to your input.

If data is a numpy array, then:
`data = data[..., np.newaxis]` should do it.

Shape of data now will be `(batch_size, timesteps, feature)` viz. `(226, 13, 1)`.